# Turn off hdmi RPI 4B bookworm

Tags: hdmi

I want to find a way to turn on and off a HDMI connected display with simple command.
In past it used to be something with xrandr, but due to linux forever evolving, it is not working anymore.

i tried :
sudo xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --off > not working
sudo vcgencmd display_power 0 > not working
sudo xset dpms force off > not working

sudo or non sudo is same result... what it seems is that instead of something like HDMI-0, there is XWAYLAND0 as name of display

talking to chat gpt and searching the internet... like forever. This is second day i am trying to figure this out... Every time i am looking for a simple answer to a simple problem i am getting reminded why i hate linux so much... there just cannot be a simple solution, everything need to be overcomplicated. (rant)

Comment: I *feel your pain*.  OTOH, you could be dealing with a system like macOS - controlled by the world's largest corporation which ***actively limits and denies*** documentation to its users. Which one do you think works best for "people like us"?

Answer (score 1):

As you're no doubt aware, `Wayland` is **new**. In *LinuxWorld*, **new** often equates to **poorly documented**. I *wonder* if you might have better luck using the *older*, but *better-documented* graphics system: `X`??

I run all of my systems *headless*, but AIUI you can **switch** from `Wayland` to `X` using the `raspi-config` utility. Start `raspi-config` from the command line by entering the following:

```bash
sudo raspi-config
```

When the menu presents, select `6 Advanced Options`, and the *sub-menu* will list more options including `A6 Wayland Switch between X and Wayland backends`. Switch to `X`, and your older commands should (*may*?) work.

There are also a couple of *"lower-level"* solutions that may allow you to keep Wayland if you're inclined:

```bash
vcgencmd display_power 0  # `0` turns OFF; `1` turns ON
```

alternatively, install `cec-utils` & use that:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libcec3 cec-utils
echo 'standby 0' | cec-client -s -d 1    # turns OFF
echo 'on 0' | cec-client -s -d 1         # turns ON
```

REFERENCES (all obtained via search engine `raspberry pi HDMI interface`):

1. [How to automatically turn off and on your monitor from your Raspberry Pi](https://www.screenly.io/blog/2017/07/02/how-to-automatically-turn-off-and-on-your-monitor-from-your-raspberry-pi/)
2. [Using HDMI-CEC on a Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberrypi-hdmi-cec/)

Comment: Thanks Seamus, i will try both later and write if it worked. Seems not using the latest everything in  Raspberry OS is better choice for common users. I can only wish RPI foundation would not push buggy ( = not battle and time proven ) software onto its users.

Comment: @dingo27mobile: That's why I run headless.

Comment: I am somehow loosing comments here all over the stackexchange... strage. Anyways, i want to srite again that i usually use it headless too but i borked the system and can see only standard debian wallpaper (debian logo in middle), even mouse cursor stopped working and i cannot start anything via menu. At least i was able to dowload everything from pi via samba, so yeah, currently i "love" linux so much. I will reinstall whole system once again when i feel like it, probably after few months...

Comment: @dingo27mobile: Did this answer solve your problem?