Raspberry Pi 3B shows a screen with an underscore in the corner
I am using a raspberry pi 3B v1.2 with a 3.5 inch kuman display as shown here. I have installed the lcd-show drivers by doing this:
sudo rm -rf LCD-show 

git clone https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show.git 

chmod -R 755 LCD-show 

cd LCD-show/

sudo ./LCD35-show


But after doing that and enabling the spi interface in raspi-config all I see on the screen is a black screen with an underscore, image here, in the top corner of it. I have checked the sd card, it is all fine. I have also reinstalled raspbian which didn't fix anything. I am using the official raspberry pi cable and there is no undervoltage. I always correctly switch off the pi through ssh, however just to be sure I have checked the sd for corruption and there isn't any.
If it is any help, here is the boot log

Are you using a GUI?  If so, try disabling that (so you boot to console) and see if it works.  I suspect you are having a problem because the X server was replaced by Wayland on new versions of the OS.

I've booted my pi to console (It worked). Now how do I set up the gui?

I have now switched off console boot and changed to gui boot, with wayland switched on in raspi-config. Now we're back to the underscore screen

The drivers for that screen are Xorg only. Were you using X before -- it seems to be from the bootlog, but keeps restarting perhaps because of VNC server.  You could try disabling that to see if it makes any difference.  No matter what, you will have to go back to X if you want to use a GUI on the screen.  You should also try booting it with an hdmi monitor plugged in (as well as the TFT).

So I just switched off the VNC server through raspi-config. Still stuck on the underscore screen... is there a way I could get hold of a older raspbian version that uses Xorg rather than Wayland?

I've managed to get the splashscreen showing at boot... but that only shows when it boots to terminal, not to gui. When I set it to boot at gui, I get the underscore screen

The splash screen w/ the row of berries isn't really a bone fide GUI, those are just rendered on the framebuffer in console mode. You don't have to use Wayland, you can switch to X: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/145463/5538

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
